# Can not get proper time format using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need one help .I need to get proper time interval format using Javascript/Jquery.

**JS :**

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick=function(){
    var num=6;
    var sTime=9;
    var duration=1;
    var arr = [],
    endTime,
    startTime = sTime;
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    endTime = startTime + duration;
    var inp = document.createElement("input");
    inp.type = "text";
    var ampm = startTime <= 12 && endTime <= 12 ? " AM " : " PM "
    inp.setAttribute("placeholder", startTime + ampm + endTime + ampm);
    document.body.appendChild(inp);
    startTime = endTime;
  }
}
```

Here i need after 12 o clock it should be 1,2...AM/PM .In my case its coming 13 after 12PM.Here is the [Plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/lshvVmqwFH70n7KIbM8x?p=preview) to check.Please help me.

Comment: `for(var num = 0;num<24;num++) console.log(num % 12 ? (num < 12 ? num % 12 + 'AM': num % 12 + 'PM') : (num==0?'12AM':'12PM'));`

Answer (score 0):

Simple demonstration:

```
for(var num = 0;num<24;num++) 
  console.log(
    num % 12 ? 
      (num < 12 ? num % 12 + 'AM': num % 12 + 'PM') :
      (num==0?'12AM':'12PM'));
```

Or as function:

```
function to12h(hour24) {
  if (hour24 % 12) {
     return hour24 ? /*noon*/ '12 PM' : /*midnight*/ '12 AM';
  }
  return num < 12 ? num % 12 + ' AM': num % 12 + ' PM';
}
```

Or you can get it sepatately:

```
var ampm = num < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
var h12 = num % 12 || 12;
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cOdLZXanecTPQXzoL2yg?p=preview)

Comment: Can you add your answer into  plunkr  code is given.

Comment: check your answer.After 1PM its coming AM again.

Comment: It is  just not related to an answer your initial code bug, which was rewrite startTime. I fix it.